# Threejs text doesn't render

Tags: javascript, three.js

Sorry, noob question here but I'm stuck for a while on this. I'm trying to get basic Threejs text to render. Other questions asking this on StackOverflow seem to be using older Threejs APIs. The following only shows a black screen. Thanks in advance...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text Test</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


        var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        var font = loader.load(
            // resource URL
            'helvetiker_bold.typeface.json',
            // Function when resource is loaded
            function ( font ) {
                var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', {
                    font: font,
                    size: 80,
                    height: 5,
                    curveSegments: 12,
                    bevelEnabled: true,
                    bevelThickness: 10,
                    bevelSize: 8,
                    bevelSegments: 5
                } );
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
                var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                scene.add( textMesh );

                camera.position.z = 5;

                var render = function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame( render );


                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                };

                render();
            },
            // Function called when download progresses
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
            },
            // Function called when download errors
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( 'An error happened' );
            }
        );



    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's possible 2 issues.

You mentioned a warning `WARNING: 0:1: extension 'GL_ARB_gpu_shader5' is not supported`. That looks like [it might be a bug in Firefox and Safari](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9716).

Otherwise your text is huge and your camera is too close.

Use

```
camera.position.z = 500;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Yes, I checked, no errors. There were 2 warnings that I assumed were normal. Here's the 1st few lines:

"vertex"
"WARNING: 0:1: extension 'GL_ARB_gpu_shader5' is not supported
"
"1: precision highp float;
2: precision highp int;

Comment: @alxross gman is right, see this codepen: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWzXZY?editors=0010](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWzXZY?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

The URL may not work directly to load the Json file imports. first you'll have to add the file path in the imports section and then add the component name over there

```
   var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
   var font = loader.parse(helveticaRegular); 
   var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', 
   {font: font,
    size: 1,
    height: 0.1, 
    curveSegments: 20 } );
   var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 
   0xF00000 } ); 
   var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, textMaterial ); 
   this.scene.add(textMesh);
```

I have used the helveticaRegular Font file .you can add your own font by downloading TTF file and then converting in to Json :https://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/

use this code.. this will definitely solve your problem